# Error when use User defined function in mutate

Tags: r, string, error-handling, functional-programming, match

I'm working on a project having 2 dataframe - product & order
Product like:

```
product <- data.frame(SKU = c("CVL-","CVP-", "CVS-", "MugsW-11-", "MugsW-15-"),
                  TM_Product = c("Canvas", "Canvas", "Canvas", 
                                 "Mugs", "Mugs"))
```

Order: include SKU_order like

```
order <- data.frame(Order_ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                Lineitem_Sku = c("F-M-White", "MugsW-11-2005",
                                 "TS-BS-F-XL-Black", "  MugsW-15",
                                 "TS-BS-F-XL-White", "TS-BS-F-3XL"))
```

My task is find product from SKU_Order.
My expected dataframe is:
Order_ID, Lineitem_Sku, Product (match Lineitem_Sku with SKU in product data and get TM_Product corresponding)

I write my function:

```
product_get <- function(x) {
  if (is.na(x)) {
    z = NA_character_
  } else if (sum(str_detect(x, pattern = paste0("^", product$SKU))) == 0) {
    z = NA_character_
  } else {
    z = product[str_detect(x, pattern = paste0("^", product$SKU)),2] %>% 
      pull()
  }
  return(z)
}
```

But when i use it in mutate

```
order %>% 
  mutate(product = product_get(Lineitem_Sku))
```

```
1: In if (is.na(x)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Anyone can help me. Thank for all

Comment: I suspect you're using your function wrong inside of `mutate()` as `if()` isn't vectorized and you might need to use it alongside one of `purrr` functions like `map_dbl()`. Could you show how you use it inside `mutate()` and possibly some data for example?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images.Also add expected output for the data shared. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: As per the first comment: `if` is not vectorized and the function will only use the first element of `x`. The other error come from the fact that `x` has a different length from  `product$SKU`.

Comment: i updated my question. Thank bros for review my code

Comment: Tks @GioraSimchoni, i use map_chr() and it's all i want. But can i ask u a favor? Why (product = product_get(Lineitem_Sku)) is false, and when use map_ in mutate. Tks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this will be a long answer, sorry in advance, there are many things which can improve.

First, as I wrote in the comment, your function is not vectorized, as it is a simple `if()` clause. Not vectorized means that you cannot operate it on an entire vector or column of numbers, it will take just the first one and warn you. And this is what you're trying to do, with `mutate()` you're trying to iterate on an existing column to create a new one. The vectorized version of `if()` is `ifelse()`, but if you insist on using `if()` (and sometimes you should), you could use `map_chr()` from `purrr` to vectorize your function inside of `mutate()` like so:

```
library(tidyverse)

product <- data.frame(SKU = c("CVL-","CVP-", "CVS-", "MugsW-11-", "MugsW-15-"),
                      TM_Product = c("Canvas", "Canvas", "Canvas", "Mugs", "Mugs"))


order <- data.frame(Order_ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                    Lineitem_Sku = c("F-M-White", "MugsW-11-2005", "TS-BS-F-XL-Black", "MugsW-15", "TS-BS-F-XL-White", "TS-BS-F-3XL"))

product_get <- function(x){
  if(is.na(x)){
    z = NA_character_
  } else if (sum(str_detect(x, pattern = paste0("^", product$SKU))) == 0){
    z = NA_character_
  } else {
    z = product[str_detect(x, pattern = paste0("^", product$SKU)),2] %>% 
      pull()
  }
  return(z)
}

order %>% 
  mutate(product = map_chr(Lineitem_Sku, product_get))
```

And we get an error!

```
Error in UseMethod("pull") : 
  no applicable method for 'pull' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

That is because when you're using `data.frame()` (in R < 4.0.0 I think), a `character` vector of your table is automatically made a `factor` unless you specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, like so:

```
product <- data.frame(SKU = c("CVL-","CVP-", "CVS-", "MugsW-11-", "MugsW-15-"),
                  TM_Product = c("Canvas", "Canvas", "Canvas", "Mugs", "Mugs"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Another option, if you're already inside the `tidyverse` is to simply use a `tibble`:

```
product <- tibble(SKU = c("CVL-","CVP-", "CVS-", "MugsW-11-", "MugsW-15-"),
                  TM_Product = c("Canvas", "Canvas", "Canvas", "Mugs", "Mugs"))

order <- tibble(Order_ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                Lineitem_Sku = c("F-M-White", "MugsW-11-2005", "TS-BS-F-XL-Black", "MugsW-15", "TS-BS-F-XL-White", "TS-BS-F-3XL"))

order %>% 
  mutate(product = map_chr(Lineitem_Sku, product_get))
```

And we get:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Order_ID Lineitem_Sku     product
     <dbl> <chr>            <chr>  
1        1 F-M-White        NA     
2        2 MugsW-11-2005    Mugs   
3        3 TS-BS-F-XL-Black NA     
4        4 MugsW-15         NA     
5        5 TS-BS-F-XL-White NA     
6        6 TS-BS-F-3XL      NA
```

Which is hopefully what you want. But I'm not sure we are done.

First, notice you define with `paste0()` the vector of patterns each and every time the function is entered! Which is wasteful. And even then, you check it with `str_detect()` twice.

```
product_patterns <- paste0("^", product$SKU)

product_get <- function(x) {
  if (is.na(x)) {
    return(NA_character_)
  }
  check <- str_detect(x, pattern = product_patterns)
  if (sum(check) == 0) {
    z <- NA_character_
  } else {
    z <- product %>%
      filter(check) %>%
      pull(TM_Product)
  }
  return(z)
}

order %>% 
  mutate(product = map_chr(Lineitem_Sku, product_get))
```

Second, this function might still fail if the input is changed just a bit. Suppose I add just one more "Mugs" row to `product`:

```
product <- tibble(SKU = c("CVL-","CVP-", "CVS-", "MugsW-11-", "MugsW-15-", "MugsW-11"),
                  TM_Product = c("Canvas", "Canvas", "Canvas", "Mugs", "Mugs", "Mugs"))

order %>% 
  mutate(product = map_chr(Lineitem_Sku, product_get))
```

Another error!

```
Error: Result 2 must be a single string, not a character vector of length 2
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

This is because you explicitly count on finding just one product, and here the function found two products. `map_chr()` assumes each of the elements it returns is a single string and throws an error. So you might want to look at `map()` which returns a list, or improve on your function to not fail like this (e.g. returning the first product).

If your data is big I'd also look at somehow doing all this with a `inner_join()`.